# EnvelopeAPI to update

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use the C# client library to update an envelope to voided status.
Is such a function available using the C# client library or should I write API calls to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code that uses the C# client library to void an Envelope:

```
Envelope envInfo = new Envelope();
envInfo.Status = "voided";
envInfo.VoidedReason = "Transaction cancelled";

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
envelopesApi.Update(accountId, envelopeId, envInfo);
```

(Of course, you'll need to replace **accountId** and **envelopeId** in the sample code above with your real values.)

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is available in the C# client library. 
If you're using DocuSign.eSign library (latest) look at EnvelopeSummary class and it has the Status property that you can just add "Voided" as the value you want.
If you're using the older C# client - there's a way to do that too.